# Private Transactions inside Smart Contract

Tags: smart-contract, privacy

Is there a way to make some transactions private inside a smart contract?

It's needed for a game theoretic model. Like imagine poker on blockchain: you'd like not to reveal cards until some point in game.

Answer (score 1):

No, transactions are always public.

If you want to hide content this is usually done through encryption. The user would at the end decrypt their secrets.

For a poker game the dealer would encrypt the distributed cards and push it to the chain.

Comment: Keep in mind, however, that the encrypted transaction is still public and can be brute forced or cracked by a determined adversary.